# Deleting image files removed from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, image, dataframe, directory

In preparation for a multi-class CNN, I read in some data to a Pandas DataFrame from a csv file.  I then dropped unwanted columns from the DataFrame. Only the Label column `Retinopathy grade` and the image column `Image name` remain.

```
idrid.head()
```

```
    Image name  Retinopathy grade
0   IDRiD_001   3
1   IDRiD_002   3
2   IDRiD_003   2
3   IDRiD_004   3
4   IDRiD_005   4
```

I rename the `Image name` column so it ends in .jpg

```
idrid['Image name'] = idrid['Image name'].apply(lambda x : "{}{}".format(x, ".jpg"))

idrid['Image name'] = idrid['Image name'].astype(str)
```

`idrid.head()`

```
mage name   Retinopathy grade
0   IDRiD_001.jpg   3
1   IDRiD_002.jpg   3
2   IDRiD_003.jpg   2
3   IDRiD_004.jpg   3
4   IDRiD_005.jpg   4
```

I removed all rows containing a Retinopathy grade of 0 from the  DataFrame, leaving only Retinopathy grades 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
idrid = idrid[idrid['Retinopathy grade'] !=0]
```

The corresponding train images denoted in the `Image name` column are .png format and are located in the same working directory as the notebook containing the idris DataFrame. Just to be certain though,
the images filepath is:

```
/Users/myname/courses/phase_5/capstone/IDRiD-Data/Original_Images/Traing_set
```

How do I delete the training images in that directory which were removed from the idrid DataFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a list of files in your directory

`mypath = /Users/myname/courses/phase_5/capstone/IDRiD-Data/Original_Images/Traing_set`

using

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
allfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

Filter out the images that are not present in your current data frame but are present in the list allfiles using,

```
to_be_kept = dataframe['Image name'].tolist()
to_be_deleted = [item for item in allfiles if item not in to_be_kept ]
```

now iterate over all the images in the list to_be_deleted using

```
os.remove()
```

like below.

```
import os
for file in to_be_deleted:
    os.remove(join(mypath, file))
```

To avoid all the extra work you can save the Image name to a list where Retinopathy grade == 0 and remove them from there.

In that case, you will not have to do anything but just run the last for loop for os.remove(file).

Comment: Its because the file path is missing from the `os.remove()` command. 
use this `os.remove(mypath +"/" +file)` instead of `os.remove(file)`

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm upvoting your answer and marking it as correct. Thanks a lot. Would you mind editing the answer to include the os.remove(join(mypath, file)) line. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I just recently worked on a project in python wherein I was making matplotlib graphs, inserting them into an excel file, and then removing them for my machine. What worked best for me was the os.remove() function. Since all the files were saved to the same directory as my program, I just did:

```
os.remove("foobar.png")
```

In your case, if the files are not saved in the same directory as your program, I believe you are able to insert the whole filepath as a parameter and it should remove the file from your system.

Something akin to this should work for you:

```
os.remove("/Users/myname/courses/phase_5/capstone/IDRiD-Data/Original_Images/Traing_set/filename.png")
```

If I recall correctly you will need to make some changes to the filepath so it can be properly interpreted, I believe double forward slashes may be the answer but I am uncertain as of now. If I figure it out I will update this answer to reflect what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Mitchnoff. The images are in the same working directory. Is there a way for me to remove only the specific images that were dropped from the dataframe in the manner you described?